# MoveByOffset with Selenium in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, coordinates

I have an element that I have no problem clicking, but am trying to use MoveByOffset to click other places on the page. The element I reference is small, just a single button. I'm not sure how to measure it, but it appears to be the size of any search engine "Search" button for instance. When running the following code:

```
Thread.Sleep(4000);
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.MoveToElement(element).MoveByOffset(4000, 0).Click();
IAction clickNextElement = builder.Build();
clickNextElement.Perform();
```

with

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
```

on Firefox, I can replace MoveByOffset()'s first parameter with -4000, 100, -100, or any similar number on different scales, but the referenced element is always clicked. Am I missing something? Firefox version 25.0.1, Selenium version 2.37.0.

Edit: I have found this to be an issue 3578 with Firefox. This works with .NET in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CHANGELOG](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG) for Selenium 2.38 implies that native events were broken by FF25, perhaps causing a fallback to synthetic events, and thus catching you in issue 3578.  Try the newest Selenium.